# GSL elliptic integral with complex arguments

Tags: debugging, c++11, complex-numbers, gsl, typeconverter

I am using C++. When using elliptical integrals defined in the gsl scientific library, I got the following error that the `gsl_sf_ellint_P` function only accept arguments of the `<double>` type. I know Mathematica can deal with complex inputs as well. Anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

The error message is as follows:

```
*evaporation-dS-xrx.cpp:37:52: error: cannot convert ‘std::complex<double>’ to ‘double’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘double gsl_sf_ellint_F(double, double, gsl_mode_t)’
             sqrt((0.5-I*0.866025)),GSL_PREC_DOUBLE) - (0.107722-I*0.18658)*
*
```

Answer (score 0):

GSL doesn't directly support the evaluation of elliptic integrals of complex arguments. You will have to do a little maths yourself to compute the real and imaginary parts.

The required transformation can be found in [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/). Specifically equation 17.4.11.

[image]

Where the values of lambda and mu are given as functions of phi and psi.

Note that they use slightly different notation than the GSL docs. Where their m is k^2 in the GSL versions of the functions.

Comment: Very Clear answer! Thank you Simon. I really appreciate it!  I also saw complex numbers in the second argument of the F function, but I didn't see a transformation formula in A&S. And what about the Pi function in which all 3 of my arguments are complex? Thanks again!

Comment: Note that Abramowitz and Stegun only gives $\cot^2(\lambda)$ and $\tan^2(\mu)$ which only determines $\lambda$ and $\mu$ up to branches.

Comment: @RuifengDong Where you able to implement this? I even got trouble to understand (is there a printing error in the book?) the euqations for $\lambda$ and $\mu$ in the book. And how would we need to solve them?